# Are there any non lethal devils other than Pochita in Chainsaw Man?

Tags: chainsaw-man

Currently, the devils showed in the episodes are lethal and intended to kill humans. But are there any small and non lethal devils other than Pochita that can be petted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-lethal devils from Chainsaw man include "Bucky" the chicken devil, which takes the form of a headless chicken with a groovy bowtie.

[image: Bucky the chicken devil, Chainsawman chapter 98]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but if there are, then they would be extremely rare.
In the very first chapter of Chainsaw Man, it's shown that devils are the natural enemies of humans. They are attracted to the human soul, which is like a "light" to them, and they will instinctively try to eat it.

> Devils were attracted to the soul like a light, so they would instinctively try to eat it.

We also know that there are different types of devils, some of which are more aggressive than others.

> Devils come in different shapes, sizes and types. There are those that are aggressive and those that have been completely pacified.

So, it's possible that there are some devils that are naturally less aggressive and more docile, but if they exist, they would be rare.